# PrimeFaces commandButton needs to validate two calendar component and then redirect an external URL that contains the two calendar value to a new page

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces

I'm new to JSF and primefaces and I'm trying to do the following: I have to create a URL that contains two date and then open it in a new page. I'm using primefaces, so I create two p:calendar component, and a p:commandButton.

My problem is, that I managed to validate the calendars and after that open the URL, but in the same window. If I set ajax="false" to the commandbutton, and target="_blank" to the form, then it opens the URL in a new page, but if the calendars value are invalid, then it also opens the original page in a new page with the validation message. For redirection I use FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(URL) in my bean.

I also tried to redirect using h:outputLink and set its value to bean.url and target="_blank". It redirects to a new page, but in this case I didn't manage to validate the calendars.

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either conditionally render a `<h:outputScript>` with `window.open()` depending on validation:

```
<h:form>
    <p:calendar validator="yourValidator" />
    <p:calendar validator="yourValidator" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}" update="@form" />
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
        window.open('someURL');
    </h:outputScript>
</h:form>
```

or use PrimeFaces' `RequestContext#execute()` with `window.open()`:

```
public void submit() { 
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('someURL');");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the window.open opens the url as an internal page (http://ip_address:port/mywebapp/url) but I need to open just the url itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Just open the URL itself then?

Comment: For example if I run this: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('www.google.com');");, then it isn't open the google site.

Comment: You should specify an absolute URL with the scheme, otherwise it's of course relative to the current URL.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that.